# How to install xxx.app.dSYM file on iPhone using iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, itunes

I been distributed with myapp.app.dSYM and myapp.mobileprovision files, is it possible to install the app on device using these two files using iTunes? if yes. please mention how?

Note : I tried to drag and drop myapp.app.dSYM and myapp.mobileprovision on iTunes, only myapp.mobileprovision is installed on device (Settings>General>Profiles) but myapp.app.dSYM is not getting listed in the Sync apps in iTunes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make installable ad-hoc package you should Archive your project, then select archive in Organizer and press Distribute button, then select "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment", sign it and you'll get ipa file. Drag this ipa file to iTunes library and sync with your device to install it.

p.s. dSYM file it's just debugger information to symbolicate crashlogs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can I do it with dSYM file or it need to be done on using Xcode with source code? please clarify. I did not installed signing certificate on my machine.

Comment: You can install only ipa file via iTunes. dSYM is usless, it's not a executable file.